# I want to save my photos from iPad OS9.3.2 to PC Windows

Tags: ipad, photos, contacts

I am planning on giving my iPad to son.  I want to reset it for him but, first, I want to offload the photos and contacts onto my PC. I have found that if I use the iCloud, as soon as I shut iCloud off, all the photos and contacts are gone from PC. This is a pain. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

For photos:

1. Connect your iPad to PC
2. Open Computer>Portable Devices>Internal Storage>DCIM, then drag/copy
   photos to another folder on your PC

For contacts:

1. Log in to your iCloud account from a browser on your computer
2. Select one or more contacts in the contacts list.
3. To select several adjacent contacts, click the first one, then
   Shift-click the last one. To select multiple nonadjacent contacts,
   Command-click them on a Mac or Control-click them on a Windows
   computer.
4. Click the cogwheel button on the bottom right and choose Export
   vCard from the pop-up menu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201302
And here is the troubleshooting page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204597
Hope that helps.